# SQL Server 2016 Linked Server table shows not up today data

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2016 Linked Server table shows not up today data
I gave appropriate access to table to remote user.
Looks like table shows last week data.

Comment: check if your linked server points to production or some copy of the db.

Comment: thank you ..It does pointed to production :-)Its something mysterious about Linked servers returning up to date data. I have been searching online for couple of days.. following some hints - but it didn't help.

Comment: Please show some examples

Comment: select employee, max(trans_date) maxtrans_date 
from mytable 
where column1='MM' 
group by employee
order  by 1 ----shows today maxtrans_date….2)select employee, max(trans_date) maxtrans_date 
from [LinkedServer].[DatabaseName].[dbo].mytable 
where column1='MM' 
group by employee
order  by 1   - shows last week  maxtrans_date

Comment: It doesn't look possible, please check your connection strings.

Comment: It's not possible. A linked server makes a direct connection to the target database in real time - right now. If you connect to the server itself and run the exact same query there, omitting the linked server part of the qualified name, you will receive the same exact results. If you don't, then your linked server is not pointed at the right place or you possibly have a security discrepancy like RLS being in place.

Comment: GoG thank you for your post..I used different providers for Linked Server as SQL Server Native provider; ODBC - - can't create new Linked Sever to troubleshoot. I end up re-creating Linked Server as originally was created using OLE DB Provider for SQL Server. I know for sure that data is my table is new. Can you give me some insight on RLS security discrepancy?tnx much.

Comment: Luckily I figured it out..I re-created Linked Server and used SQL Server Native Client 10.0 as Provider. and Important! specified  'Data Source' as Server#1 instance Name -(the server I was trying to linked to and get data).Before my previous Linked Server for some weird reason was connecting to itself - that is why I was getting "old" data.